# Inform user that the app crashed previously

Tags: ios, crashlytics

I have integrated Crashlytics in my app for sending crash reports. I need to display an alert saying the app crashed in previous run stage when the app launch next time after crash.
How can I detect it crashed?
Is there any possibility using crashlytics?

Answer (score 1):

That's what the Crashlytics delegate function `crashlyticsDidDetectReport(forLastExecution report: CLSReport)` is for. Implement it e.g. in your AppDelegate to show an alert, and set `Crashlytics.sharedInstance().delegate = self`.